# What is the different between android:maxSdkVersion="18" and no?

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-manifest

What is the different between

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the highest SDK version that the permission will be applied to. This is because some permission are no longer required to be requested, say because of a change to the android framework.

As the documentation states:

> The highest API level at which this permission should be granted to
>   your app. Setting this attribute is useful if the permission your app
>   requires is no longer needed beginning at a certain API level.
>
> For example, beginning with Android 4.4 (API level 19), it's no longer
>   necessary for your app to request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>   permission when your app wants to write to its own
>   application-specific directories on external storage (the directories
>   provided by getExternalFilesDir()). However, the permission is
>   required for API level 18 and lower.

Answer (score 0):

> android:maxSdkVersion:
>
> The highest API level at which this permission should be granted to
> your app. Setting this attribute is useful if the permission your app
> requires is no longer needed beginning at a certain API level.

From developer.android.com

Answer (score -1):

From android documentation:

> android:maxSdkVersion
>   The highest API level at which this permission should be granted to your app. Setting this attribute is useful if the permission your app requires is no longer needed beginning at a certain API level.